# How to get a propertyvalue for nested properties?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to sort a list of objects, the code in my else statements works like charm but there is a column that has nested property and that's where the problem occurs. when I try to get the value of the nested property it gives me null exception. Can you help me globalize the code so I don't have this extra if in my code?

```
if (e.SortExpression == "Distribution.Coder.Name")
    lstActivities = lstActivities.OrderByDescending(o => (string)o.Distribution.Coder.Name).ToList();
else
    lstActivities = lstActivities.OrderByDescending(o => typeof(Activity).GetProperty(e.SortExpression).GetValue(o, null)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just want to shared with you this code what I found. I do not remember it reference.

```
 public static object GetPropertyValue(object obj, string name)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
        {
            return obj;
        }

        foreach (string part in name.Split('.'))
        {
            if (obj == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            Type type = obj.GetType();
            PropertyInfo info = type.GetProperty(part);
            if (info == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            obj = info.GetValue(obj, null);
        }

        return obj;
    }
```

And using:

```
 GetPropertyValue(Distribution, "Coder.Name")
```